# Subtracting each column from its previous one in a data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a very simple case here in which I would like to subtract each column from its previous one. As a matter of fact I am looking for a sliding subtraction as the first column stays as is and then the first one subtracts the second one and second one subtracts the third one and so on till the last column.
here is my sample data set:

```
structure(list(x = c(1, 0, 0, 0), y = c(1, 0, 1, 1), z = c(0, 
1, 1, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

and my desired output:

```
structure(list(x = c(1, 0, 0, 0), y = c(0, 0, 1, 1), z = c(-1, 
1, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

I am personally looking for a solution with `purrr` family of functions. I also thought about `slider` but I'm not quite familiar with the latter one. So I would appreciate any help and idea with these two packages in advance. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for `pmap_df` with `lag` to subtract the previous value.

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

pmap_df(df, ~{x <- c(...);x - lag(x, default = 0)})

# A tibble: 4 x 3
#      x     y     z
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     0    -1
#2     0     0     1
#3     0     1     0
#4     0     1     0
```

Comment: Thank you very much dear Ronak. I could not think of this simple, elegant answer in my wildest dream.

Answer (score 4):

A simple `dplyr` only solution-

- `cur_data()` inside mutate/summarise just creates a whole copy. So
- just substract `cur_data()[-ncol(.)]` from `cur_data()[-1]`
- with `pmap_df` you can do similar things

```r
df <- structure(list(x = c(1, 0, 0, 0), y = c(1, 0, 1, 1), z = c(0, 
                                                           1, 1, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))


library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(cur_data()[-1] - cur_data()[-ncol(.)])
#>   x y  z
#> 1 1 0 -1
#> 2 0 0  1
#> 3 0 1  0
#> 4 0 1  0
```

similarly

```
pmap_dfr(df, ~c(c(...)[1], c(...)[-1] - c(...)[-ncol(df)]))
```

Comment: Very nice and elegant.

Answer (score 3):

Verbose, but simple:

```
df %>%
  select(x) %>%
  bind_cols(df %>%
             select(-1) %>%
             map2_dfc(df %>%
                         select(-ncol(df)), ~.x -.y))

#  x y  z
#1 1 0 -1
#2 0 0  1
#3 0 1  0
#4 0 1  0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I really appreciate your help. This is also so elegant, unfortunately I could only choose one and I'm sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

We can just do (no need of any packages)

```
cbind(df1[1], df1[-1] - df1[-ncol(df1)])
```

-output

```
 x y  z
1 1 0 -1
2 0 0  1
3 0 1  0
4 0 1  0
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
      mutate(.[-1] - .[-ncol(.)])
```